# plotting two variables on bar graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am new to using ggplot2 and i am having trouble plotting a graph. I have looked around on SO but the solutions I found did not work with my data. 
Here is an example of my DF

```
Count1     Count2      Color 
  3         4          Red
  3         6          Green 
  5         2          Red
  2         0          Blue
```

I would like to just plot this is as a bar graph. I would like the X axis to consist of the colors and I would like to plot both the Count1 and Count2 variables on the y axis. for example, the two bars used to show the `green` color will go up to the number 3 (for `count1`) and the number 6 (for `count2`). Similarly, the `red` bar will go up to 8 (for `count1`) and 6 (for `count2`) Does anyone know how to go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Aggregate and reshape your data first, e.g. `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(Color) %>% summarise_all(sum) %>% gather(var, val, -Color) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Color, y = val, fill = var)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')`

Comment: @alistaire  when I tried the summarise_all part of your code on my real data, I got this error message and im not sure what to make of it: Error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: `summarise_all` tries to apply its function (`sum` here) to all non-grouping columns, which for the sample data is fine, but may not be for your real data if there are non-numeric columns. (Also use `str` to make sure your numeric columns are actually stored as doubles or integers.) `summarise_at` lets you specify columns, or just use `summarise` and explicitly specify what to do with each column you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking up the answer from @alistaire above, so you can follow what's going on

Your data

```
color_df <- data.frame(Count1 = c(3,3,5,2), Count2 = c(4,6,2,0), Color = c("Red", "Green", "Red", "Blue"))
```

Adding up counts for each color

```
library(dplyr)
sum_df <- color_df %>%
    group_by(Color) %>%
    summarise_all(sum)
sum_df
```

ggplot needs both counts in one column, with another column describing which is which. Compare `sum_df` and `tidy_df`

```
library(tidyr)
tidy_df <- sum_df %>%
    gather(CountName, Count, -Color)
```

Finally the plot. Dodge puts them side by side. `geom_col` uses heights from `Count` variable. `geom_bar` would count number of observations itself.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tidy_df, aes(x = Color, fill = CountName, y = Count)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. However, when I tried the group_by and summarise_all part of your code on my real data, I got this error message and im not sure what to make of it: `Error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument`

Comment: Check your counts are stored as numbers.

Comment: The likely problem is the sum. Do you have other columns apart from the counts? If so trying to sum a character column would give this error. Try replacing summarise_all with summarise (Count1 = sum(Count1), Count2 = sum(Count2))